# How to remove stairstep artifact from volume rendering of data with highly anisotropic voxels

Tags: directx, render, volume, direct3d, smoothing

I have a set of intensity-based volume data.  That data is stored in a 3 column matrix V(i,j,k) and is roughly 1k by 1k by 100 pixels (X,Y,Z).  That volume contains a 12 bit object.  The region outside the object is set to 0. The spatial dimensions of each voxel are (1 by 1 by 10), with the larger dimension corresponding to the smaller number of pixels.

We are using DirectX to display this volume.  There are 3 problems.

(1) No one in this location has any substantial experience with DirectX. (I've ordered a book...)
(2) When we display the volume, stairstep artifacts appear in the Z direction.
(3) Those stairstep artifacts appear to interact with the camera lighting to create an alternating pattern of dark and bright steps.

The most obvious step was to try changing the interpolation.  We've tried POINT, LINEAR, and ANISOTROPIC.  Those settings did not help with the stairstep pattern. The obvious steps are to try antialiasing and reduce the diffuse and specular contributions to the lighting model.  Unfortunately, antialiasing is likely to be slow and changing the lighting model removes information regarding surface orientation. In particular, I suspect we only need to antialias in only one direction.

I can simply rebin the volume and smooth the resulting object, but that increases memory usage and slows down the rendering.

I suspect that we're missing something completely obvious. So, what method in DirectX would be recommended to remove stairstep artifacts from volume rendering of data with highly anisotropic voxels?  Considerations include memory usage and speed.  We already display blurred data when interacting with the data set, so low memory usage may be more useful than speed.

Comment: How do you render the volume? There is not only one method. Have you researched about volume rendering approaches?

Comment: Bearing in mind that I've never worked with DirectX, the program seems to render the data by accepting the volumetric model and modeling it using predefined opacity and color curves.  It appears to assume a directional light source.

Comment: I've never worked with DirectX, but the program seems to render the data by accepting the volumetric model and modeling it using an optical model based on predefined opacity and color curves.  It appears to assume a directional light source.  It also does something using a pre-integration lookup table. I've researched simple projection-based rendering techniques, but only for volumes, not surfaces.  What you mean by approaches?  Do you mean different algorithms to convert volume data to 2d images or different ways to do the same thing in DirectX or something else? (Sorry...timed out.)

Comment: Ok, sounds like ray casting. Can you turn off the pre-integration? That might not be appropriate for some data sets. I guess you haven't written the rendering code yourself. What library do you use?

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I think I'd be better off writing a small project that duplicates the ray casting functionality and then work out how to eliminate the staircase.

Comment: That will require learning some DirectX. You are correct.  I didn't write the code - we are adopting a fairly ancient 'framework' from our headquarters in another country.  The framework appears to be home-built.

Comment: I will try turning off the preintegration and get back to you.  That will take a while - mostly lack of knowledge on my end, partially lack of documentation.